# Serverless RabbitMQ

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I'm just getting into RabbitMQ and I see that it must be installed on a machine and ran as a service in order to work.

Is there an alternative, for .Net, like a nuget or something that you can bundle up in an application and have it work without explicit machine installation?

My goal is to have an application that can be deployed without having to rely on a RabbitMQ server or dedicated service outside itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is not any version like NuGet or similar.

However you can provide localhost instalation of RabbitMQ server on target machine and set your connections to localhost.

There is quite good creator application for installer packages - InnoSetup:
https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

This application allows programatically start another bundled installer inside result package to you. Despite of this it is not simple "out of the box on one click" solution. You must define Delphi routine in installer script to be done.

I think there is something similar for Windows Installer service but it is provided by AD domain task configuration (I dont know if you have this opportunity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software ).